# Error message: "index 1 beyond bounds"

Tags: objective-c, ios, indexing, nsarray

I'm just a rookie and I cant seem to find the error. It's a piece of code for scaling, rotating and moving a UIImageView. I can move the UIImageView but when I try to rotate or scale the UIImageView it just crashes. I did set the setMultipleTouchEnabled to YES.

The crash is because of: `[NSArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]`

I think the error is in this part of the text:

```
    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    NSArray *allTouches = [touches allObjects];

    UITouch* t;
    if([[event allTouches] count]==1){
        if (CGRectContainsPoint([Birdie frame], [[allTouches objectAtIndex:0] locationInView:self.view])) {
            t=[[[event allTouches] allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
            touch1=[t locationInView:nil];
        }
    }else{
        t=[[[event allTouches] allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
        touch1=[t locationInView:nil];
        t=[[[event allTouches] allObjects] objectAtIndex:1];
        touch2=[t locationInView:nil];
    }
}

-(double)distance:(CGPoint)point1 toPoint:(CGPoint)point2
{
    double deltaX, deltaY;
    deltaX = point1.x - point2.x;
    deltaY = point1.y - point2.y;
    return sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    CGPoint currentTouch1;
    CGPoint currentTouch2;
    NSArray *allTouches = [touches allObjects];
    UITouch* t;
    float scale,rotation;

    if([[event allTouches] count]==1){
        t=[[[event allTouches] allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint([Birdie frame], [[allTouches objectAtIndex:0] locationInView:self.view]))
        { 
            touch2=[t locationInView:nil];
            Birdie.center=CGPointMake(Birdie.center.x+touch2.x-touch1.x,Birdie.center.y+touch2.y-touch1.y);
            touch1=touch2;
        }
    }
    else if([[event allTouches] count]==2)
    {
        t=[[[event allTouches] allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
        currentTouch1=[t locationInView:nil];

        t=[[[event allTouches] allObjects] objectAtIndex:1];
        currentTouch2=[t locationInView:nil];

        double distance1 =  [self distance:currentTouch1 toPoint:currentTouch2];
        double distance2 = [self distance:touch1 toPoint:touch2];

        if (distance2 == 0)
        {
            //handle the case where distance is zero
        }
        else {
            scale =distance1 / distance2;}

        rotation=atan2(currentTouch2.y-currentTouch1.y, currentTouch2.x-currentTouch1.x)-atan2(touch2.y-touch1.y,touch2.x-touch1.x);
        if(isnan(scale)){
            scale=1.0f;
        }
        NSLog(@"rotation %f",rotation);

        NSLog(@"scale %f",scale);

        if (CGRectContainsPoint([Birdie frame], [[allTouches objectAtIndex:0] locationInView:self.view]) &&
            CGRectContainsPoint([Birdie frame], [[allTouches objectAtIndex:1] locationInView:self.view]))
        {

            Birdie.transform=CGAffineTransformScale(Birdie.transform, scale,scale);
            Birdie.transform=CGAffineTransformRotate(Birdie.transform, rotation);
        }
        else // In case of scaling or rotating the background imageView
        {
            imageView.transform=CGAffineTransformScale(imageView.transform, scale,scale);
            imageView.transform=CGAffineTransformRotate(imageView.transform, rotation);
        }

        touch1=currentTouch1;
        touch2=currentTouch2;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you make this call:

```
  if (CGRectContainsPoint([Birdie frame], [[allTouches objectAtIndex:0] locationInView:self.view]) &&
            CGRectContainsPoint([Birdie frame], [[allTouches objectAtIndex:1] locationInView:self.view]))
```

Make sure you have indeed two touch objects in allTouches.

Answer (score 2):

if you are working with thew tableview then remember to set this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
   if(tableview == self.table1)
    {
      return [mydictionaryObject count]; 
    }

}
```

Comment: You should have another `return` in case the `if` condition is false.